# Request Method in Cron Jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, request

When I try to execute a task in cron job, it fails. On checking it I came to know that the request  method sent via cron is a GET but in my API for that endpoint I have configured it as a **DELETE**. So is it possible to configure the request method type in cron.xml.

Comment: cron.xml is deprecated. Have you considered Cloud Scheduler?

Comment: Even if I use cron.yaml is it possible to configure any request method?

Comment: No,  you can define the HTTP verb and content (except for GET) only with Cloud Scheduler

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to configure the HTTP verb in App Engine Cron Jobs[[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml)
As @guillaume blaquiere indicated, the best solution would be to use Cloud Scheduler [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#creating_jobs).

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create http JOB --schedule=SCHEDULE --uri=URI --http-method=delete [optional flags]
```